# Correct term for percentage in decimal form (repost)

Tags: percentages, unit-of-measure

I am looking for a precise term of the "decimal form of percentage" - f.x. 0.35 instead of 35%.
It was previously discussed 6 years ago ([Correct term for percentage in decimal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350980/correct-term-for-percentage-in-decimal-form)) and some good suggestions came up.

I could go with percent decimal or similar, but I wonder if there is a better term. I like the term "per unit" (taken from the field of electrical engineering) because I think it is a logical parallel to percent - though it has a different meaning in its original context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a "form of percentage" - in fact, what you are doing is simply *not using* percentages.

You could describe this as a "proportion", for example "it costs $\$5$ plus tax at a proportion of $0.15$".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its ofcourse true. What I was really looking for, was a sort of pseudo-unit to assign to the value in a database. The per-unit seemed like a good unit, and could be beautifully abbreviated to [p.u.] :)
But I'm gonna go with a unitless value, and describe it as a proportion.